# Kallithea (waitress) not starting

Tags: python, pylons, waitress, kallithea

I made Kallithea's installation (into virtualenv) according to official guide.
Then, I got following error:

```
(metal)1:17:46 root@dervish mercurial paster serve my.ini
2015-04-26 01:17:49.003 INFO  [kallithea.model] initializing db for sqlite:////opt/scm/mercurial/kallithea.db?timeout=60
2015-04-26 01:17:49.003 INFO  [kallithea.lib.auth] getting information about all available permissions
Starting server in PID 12321.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/scm/mercurial/metal/bin/paster", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PasteScript==1.7.5', 'console_scripts', 'paster')()
  File "/opt/scm/mercurial/metal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 104, in run
    invoke(command, command_name, options, args[1:])
  File "/opt/scm/mercurial/metal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 143, in invoke
    exit_code = runner.run(args)
  File "/opt/scm/mercurial/metal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 238, in run
    result = self.command()
  File "/opt/scm/mercurial/metal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/serve.py", line 311, in command
    serve()
  File "/opt/scm/mercurial/metal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/serve.py", line 295, in serve
    server(app)
  File "/opt/scm/mercurial/metal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 189, in server_wrapper
    **context.local_conf)
  File "/opt/scm/mercurial/metal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/util.py", line 55, in fix_call
    val = callable(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/scm/mercurial/metal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress/__init__.py", line 21, in serve_paste
    serve(app, **kw)
  File "/opt/scm/mercurial/metal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress/__init__.py", line 11, in serve
    server = _server(app, **kw)
  File "/opt/scm/mercurial/metal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress/server.py", line 39, in create_server
    adj = Adjustments(**kw)
  File "/opt/scm/mercurial/metal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress/adjustments.py", line 176, in __init__
    raise ValueError('Unknown adjustment %r' % k)
ValueError: Unknown adjustment 'http'
```

PS: Only few options was touched in config.
P.P.S: This secrion in config (my.ini) unclear for me:

```
[server:main]
## PASTE ##
# use = egg:Paste #http
## nr of worker threads to spawn
threadpool_workers = 3
## max request before thread respawn
threadpool_max_requests = 10
## option to use threads of process
use_threadpool = true

## WAITRESS ##
use = egg:waitress#main
## number of worker threads
threads = 5
## MAX BODY SIZE 100GB
max_request_body_size = 107374182400
## use poll instead of select, fixes fd limits, may not work on old
## windows systems.
#asyncore_use_poll = True
```

I tried to comment out **use = egg:Paste** with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

This section allows you to select an HTTP server to use and to specify its options. You can select (`use =`) only one at a time, and you need to specify only those options it understands (they're different for different HTTP servers). So choose one and configure just it, comment out the rest.